# Release branching always results in merge conflicts

Tags: git, merge

We're responsible for several repositories and there are a few that always require manual merge conflict resolution.  Here's the workflow we follow:

**Development**

- New `feature-branch` created from `develop`
- Commits are done to `feature-branch`
- Pull request opened to merge from `feature-branch` to `develop`

  - There may be multiple feature branches in development so sometimes `develop` is merged into the feature branch to pull in other users' changes before opening a pull request

**Release**

- Once per month a new `release-candidate` branch is created from `master`
- `develop` is merged in to `release-candidate`

  - This is where things go sideways, as described below
- `release-candidate` is merged to `master` via pull request

We always have merge conflicts when merging `develop` in to the `release-candidate` branch.  I go in and manually accept all incoming changes, then create a pull request to merge `release-candidate` into `master`.

If you look at the commit history in `master` it's all like this:

> Merge pull request #102 in repo-name from release-candidate-3 (squashed)

> Merge pull request #101 in repo-name from release-candidate-2 (squashed)

Doesn't seem like anyone has committed directly to master for at least a year.  Is there something wrong with this workflow?  Are there common reasons why we don't see this issue in other repos but always do in another?

Comment: It's the "squashed" (i.e. what you're doing when the pull request is approved). A squash is not a merge. Over on the other repos that work fine, you're not making that mistake; you are _merging_ the pull request, which is the right thing to do.

Comment: When merging the pull request these are the options for Merge Strategy:


1. Squash, fast-forward only (default)
 2. Merge commit

You're saying if we switch this repo to default to "merge commit" this won't happen?

Comment: We're still interesting in the clean history that squashing allows.  So perhaps it makes sense to do a squash when merging from our feature branches to develop, then do a merge commit when going from the release-candidate branch to master?

Comment: Real merging gives you a clean history too: it's just a matter of *viewing* the history correctly. :-) Using `git log --first-parent`, your Git will only show you the *first* parent of each merge commit, and not show the set of commits that made up the feature: you will see only the merge, as if it were a squash-merge. (Note that `git log -p` won't show a *diff* for the merge unless you add `-m` to the command, so to make the view similar to `git log -p` when using squash-merges, use `git log --first-parent -m -p`.)

Comment: "release-candidate is merged to master via pull request" -- do you expect to be any difference between `release-candidate` and the `master` after it's merged? Are there any changes which should be only in `master`?